# Unable to move (click and drag) entities in MySQL Workbench EER Diagram

Tags: mysql, database, model, mysql-workbench, eer-model

I am modelling a database using MySQL Workbench - EER model. Now, I would like to move around certain entities so I can wrap them in separate layer for better visual look. My problem is that I am not able to move entities on EER diagram, using "click and drag" technique. Also, I would like to select some area, to surround certain entities and put them in layer. "Select objects" (mouse arrow) is selected tool.

Is it maybe that diagram editor is in some kind of locked mode?
Maybe I have pressed some shortcut key or enabled/disabled some option, but I can't find where to enable moving entities on EER diagram.

Appreciate any help.

EDIT:
I made this model using MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu Linux machine. There, I was able to drag entities on diagram. But, now I have opened this model on my other computer, where I have Windows 7, and latest MySQL Workbench (6.1). Could that be a problem? Because MySQL Workbench on linux is pretty unstable and crashes from time to time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug in 6.1.6.11834 build 1642 (but currently being the latest workbench, you can't yet update to fix). I also have this problem...

The first time any EER Diagram is opened or created, tables can happily be click-and-dragged about, but closing and immediately reopening the diagram with tables *tends* to prevent click and drag operations. To fix try opening and closing additional EER diagrams and the tables may come unstuck, but a definite fix it to close the model first, then restart workbench.

Most simple repro:
New model, new EER Diagram, create a new empty table, close the diagram, reopen that diagram, table can't be moved.

New: I reported this bug and have been notified it will be fixed in the 6.2.2 release

Comment: In 6.3.7 bug still happend. Where do you report? I want reopen :)

Comment: The marked answer used to work when I had two tables only. Now, even if I reopen workbench nothing changes. Also you can't even add foreign keys manually so. The software is quite useless.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to EER Diagram tab with your problems
2. In menu: Model - Diagram Properties and Size...
3. In the Diagram Properties window enter 2 in Width field
4. OK button